# What's the reasoning behind phrase "dissertation submitted in partial fulfillment of the requirements"?

Tags: thesis

Phrase "dissertation submitted in **partial** fulfillment of the requirements" seems strange. Can one submit dissertation in **full** fulfillment of the requirements?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Most doctoral programs have other requirements for completion of the degree, such as  a certain number of course hours and the passing of qualifying exams. Hence, while the dissertation is the culmination of the doctoral program, on its own it does not satisfy all the requirements for graduation.